# Resource isolation by the users created in same AD in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I need to create multiple users in same AD and need to isolate the resources created by one user from other user.Is it really possible.since I am new to Azure I am not aware that this is really possible.It would be great if some one render their hands to advice on this.

Comment: You mean the resources in the subscription or in the AAD?

Comment: Hi Joy, I mean resources in the AAD

Comment: can the above implemented in the subscription?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just use the RBAC roles.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

Comment: Thats great! Good to hear..Thanks a ton Joy Wang!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no absolute isolation, there are only certain restrictions.

The users created in the AAD tenant are all the `Member`s by default, they have the default permissions e.g. `Read all properties of groups`, `Read properties of registered and enterprise applications`. So if user A created some resources e.g. group, application, the user B will also be able to read the properties of them.

There are some restrictions, like `Manage properties, ownership, and membership of groups the user owns`, `Manage application properties, assignments, and credentials for owned applications`. This means some properties of the resources can just be managed by the `Owner` of them.

For more details about the default user permissions, you could refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions

And if the user is assigned as the admin role in the tenant, he will have more permissions than the default users, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles

Comment: Thankyou Joy.can we implement the above request in the subscription?